# How do i examine the contents of a file named "-" (a single hyphen) on disk?

Tags: file, unix, command-line-arguments, stdin

I don't know how it got there, and I want to know what it contains. But every command I've tried, such as `cat -`, `cat \-`, `vim -`, `vim \-`, etc. simply start listening in on STDIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the filename begins with a hyphen, it's common to prefix it with `./` giving, in your examples, `cat ./-` or `vim ./-`.  That is, the file named `-`, in the current directory `./`.

The `\` escapes that you're using are parsed by the shell before it executes `cat` or `vim`.  Whereas the `-` filename is given special treatment by those programs, not the shell, and giving the escape to the shell doesn't alter the behaviour of the program.

You'll need this not only when the whole filename is `-`, but also when it begins that way, as most programs will assume that it's a switch.  Some tools accept a special `--` argument which separates switches from filenames, but this is not universal.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can also use something like vim `pwd`/- 

`pwd`
```

expands to your current directory, so this basically uses the full filepath to disambiguate - the filename from - the indication of an option

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was `cat <(-)`. This is the input redirection feature of the shell.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @duDE I am the author. I actually discovered it halfway through writing the question, I just know other people have and will encounter this "issue".  I am also extremely curious to find out why you might think that this doesn't constitute an answer. In any case, I'll expand on it a little bit to explain it